# Flutter "Hot Reload" button becomes disabled (gray-out) when connecting iPhone device

Tags: flutter

I've installed Flutter developer environment and run the initial app as official document mentioned.

I ran the code in Android Studio in my iPhone device (not emulator).

The app was correctly launched in my iPhone, but "Hot Reload" button in Android studio is disabled as following screenshot shows.

[image]

How can I make it enabled ??

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.

As a temporary measure, 'close that project and re-open' worked for me.